# How can I see the axis of rectangle rotates?

Tags: html, css

The red rectangle around the axis X, Y-webkit-transform-origin
Is it possible to see visually the Axis?

[Demo Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/hfuGx/38/)

Comment: I don't think this is possible, nice question though.

Comment: I create a circle on rectangle but I don't know how to focus it on the axis Please Help Thx  [Demo Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/hfuGx/39/)

Comment: `#div3` has to be child of the rotated `DIV` and I also set it to `position: absolute;`: http://jsfiddle.net/hfuGx/40/ + inserted Opera vendor prefixes to test it here. This is a nice workaround to your question.